# If $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$ exists, does $f'(c)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

**Here's a problem on differentiability at a point and continuity of the derivative function at the same point. I'm stating the problem and presenting my solution to it. I'm not entirely confident on my solution (especially about interchanging the limits). So I'd greatly appreciate if someone checks the solution and tell me if there's any gap in my arguments. Thank you.**

> **The Problem :** Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and is differentiable except possibly at $c \in (a,b)$. Assume that $\lim_{x \to c} f'(x)$ exists. Show that $f'(c)$ exists and $f'$ is continuous at $c$.

**My Approach :** Given that $\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)$ exists, we can write
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)&=\lim_{x \to c} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} ~~\text{[Since the double-limit exists]}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \Big[\frac{1}{h} \cdot \lim_{x \to c}\big\{f(x+h)-f(x)\big\}\Big]\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h} ~~\text{[Since $f$ is continuous]}\\
\end{align}
Since $\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)$ exists, so does $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h},$ i.e. $f'(c)$. Clearly, $\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)=f'(c)$. Hence $f'$ is continuous at $c$. $~\blacksquare$

**P.S. The problem is from an exercise consisting of Mean Value Theorem (MVT)-related problems. So it is highly likely that MVT should play a role here, which makes me suspect this is a comparatively simple, probably too-simple-to-be-correct solution.**

Comment: existence of a double limit is not enough to exchange limits. There are plenty of examples of a double sequence converging to different values when the order of limits is different.

Comment: BTW contrary to what you think a solution of a limit problem via use of double limit is not simple. The simpler / correct approach is the use of mean value theorem (and you also say it is a mean value related problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Since the double limit exists." That seems a bit suspicious to me as justification for switching the order of limits. What result are you basing this on? I see a gap there.

There's actually an even simpler too-simple-to-be-correct solution: Let $L= \lim_{x\to c}f'(x).$ By the MVT,

$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = \frac{f'(c_x)(x-c)}{x-c} = f'(c_x).$$

As $x\to c,$ $c_x \to c.$ From the given hypothesis it follows that $f'(c_x)\to L.$ Therefore $f'(c)=L.$

Comment: This proof is given in Spivak's wonderful *Calculus*. He does mention it is a rather unknown fact.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: this proof is given almost a century ago by Hardy in his *A Course of Pure Mathematics*. It is rather very unfortunate that this book never became popular and Spivak which only repeats what Hardy said became all too popular. This is probably one of the reasons that "it is a rather unknown fact".

Comment: +1 for the simplest possible solution. Another approach is Darboux theorem. Btw the phrase *too-simple-to-be-correct* does seem to indicate that even this is proof is wrong. But I think OP will understand your intent in using this phrase.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second equation $ \frac{f'(c_h)(x-c)}{(x-c)}$ and how do we show formally that $c_h \to c$ as $ x \to c$

Comment: @matt The MVT is sometimes stated as $f(x)-f(c) = f'(c_x)(x-c)$ so I was covering all bases. Now $c_x$ lies between $c$ and $x.$ So we have $|c_x-c|<|x-c|.$ Thus $x\to c$ forces $c_x\to c.$